# Installation failed due to container error - Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin

I own a Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android version: 4.1.2) and I'm trying to deploy an application from Xamrin Studio. The result is: "Deployment Failed. Internal Error". In the log it says:

> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Installation failed due to container error. This can be caused by lack of available space on the SD card or stale files left behind from previous installations.

I've checked the available space and i suppose it's not the problem - Empty SD card and 3GB free in the phone memory.

More things I tried:

- Uncheck "Fast assembly deployment" - didn't work.
- Tried to deploy an application using "Dot42", and it worked with no problems.
- Change "Install location" to "internalOnly" - didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, made a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

That is a seriously old phone, which does not have 3gb of memory to install programs on. On Android the internal storage is split between an area you can put music movies and photos on and an area that you can install programs on. The 3gb is the area you can put media on, you should check for the size of the area you can put programs on, which is quite small on that phone.

Comment: Thanks, but I made a factory reset before I saw your answer and it solved the problem.